# How to Install FFMpeg on centos 6 in 2022?

Tags: ffmpeg, yum, centos6, repo

a client of mine asked to add videos to their website, i decided to install FFMpeg on their server so whenever they upload a video, the service automatically generates the first frame for the preview and encodes them in webm.

Sadly it seems to be impossible to install without having to compile it myself (which i don't really want to do as i have never done it before and don't want to risk breaking something in their server),

The server is running cento6 but EVERY repository that provides the centos6 version of FFMpeg seem to use dependencies from dead hosts (they are offline and unreachable), every solution i find ends up with the same error like "Couldn't resolve host 'apt.sw.be'"

I've changed yam repositories, installed apt-get to try with that instead of yam, disabled and enable repos like nux that seem to be very outdated, even followed posts that were published/updated recently like [this](https://www.xmodulo.com/how-to-set-up-rpmforge-repoforge-repository-on-centos.html) but they all keep ending up with the the same "Couldn't resolve host..." when installing decencies.

Is there any live and updated repo that provides a way to install FFMpeg for centos6 with yum or apt-get in 2022?

Thanks

*EDIT*
Following Romeo's tip about downloading the binaries, i managed to install it but in my case i needed a older 32 bit version to make it work (else i'd get Kernel too old):

```
$ wget https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/old-releases/ffmpeg-4.0.3-32bit-static.tar.xz
$ tar xvf ffmpeg-4.0.3-32bit-static.tar.xz
$ sudo mv ffmpeg-4.0.3-32bit-static/ffmpeg ffmpeg-4.0.3-32bit-static/ffprobe /usr/local/bin/
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to try to install statically build `ffmpeg` binary. This will help you not to search for contemporary package and update your CentOS.
You can try [this version](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-amd64-static.tar.xz) (64bit version).

Comment: Thanks, managed to add those binaries manually, sadly now i need to find a solution for the "kernel too old" error...

Comment: @RubenFernandes, you can try with old versions from the same site: https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/old-releases/